# Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?

Tags: discussion, status-bydesign, down-votes

I've got a particular answer that got downvoted a couple of times, for reasons I don't understand. I'm not particularly concerned about the odd point of rep (though for us low-rung ladder people, it all counts!), but I'm more bothered because I really don't understand what was wrong with the answer I gave. I can understand no votes, but for it to be actively downvoted has puzzled me.

Without the downvoter commenting to my answer, I'm left stuck without any further recourse. How can I tell who downvoted it?

Please note — I'm not a saddo looking to indulge in some pathetic tit-for-tat. I'm just puzzled because the question couldn't really have a "wrong" answer.

The question is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1048982/1050056#1050056), although I've since noticed it on another answer of mine too.

Comment: I agree; hit-and-run downvotes are, at best, pointless. Obviously you can’t expect *everybody* who votes down to leave a comment, particularly if there are already comments to explain existing down-votes; if the reason you think a post is bad has already been explained by someone else, repeating it is pointless. However if there are no comments or other down-votes, then a hit-and-run down-vote comes off as (and often *is*) just someone being petty or spiteful for some reason. Hiding their identity only makes it possible and easy to do this instead of making people accountable for their votes.

Comment: @Synetech it's easy to solve the duplicate downvote reason problem, simply write a reference to the other down voters' reason. At the same time, it's good to not reveal the downvoter's identity. The CS community is a mix of saints and thugs, so downvote quality control is especially important.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

No, basically. Add a comment saying that you'd like comments with downvotes - that's about all you can do.

It's a pain, but there's no way to force someone to leave a meaningful comment.

Comment: be aware that this is now implemented as of yesterday http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes

Comment: I think that's the way it should be.. As has been mentioned before, although not too common, it can lead to malice, and if someone upvoted one of your posts it may make you feel like you should upvote one of their posts on another occasion, because they upvoted you, as opposed to being because of the actual content.

Comment: PLUS, you'll almost always get upvoted if you ask why you were downvoted. I haven't yet tried this on a post that didn't get downvoted at all, but for some reason, if I ask why I'm downvoted, my post usually gets upvoted.

Comment: @devinb - and you're right! For some inexplicable reason I just got 2 upvotes on that answer (it was standing at 0 this morning). :-)

Comment: @Jeff, are you referring to the div alert thing? Because I'm not seeing it...

Comment: Sorry sir, to ask something, but many people downvote almost equal answers, to get their answer on top, so they get accepted at first.

Comment: @twntee: Do you have evidence of that? Given that downvoting is anonymous, it seems hard to see what evidence you *would* have.

Comment: @JonSkeet Respected sir, yes you are absolutely right, I can't not be 100% sure that a particular person has downvoted all answers, and clearly there isn't any evidence. But just experienced something, on particular question all 5 answers were identically same, then soon all the oldest answers get downvoted -1, and one newest answer had no downvotes and also there wasn't any comment before downvoting to it.

Comment: @twntee: So *maybe* that's the situation in this *one* case. That's very different from "many people". Can you refer to the specific example?

Comment: @JonSkeet yes sir, I agree with you totally, but these type of cases aren't good for SO. I wish and hope there is some solution for it in future, as one small bug can grow up to be a big problem. Thank you for replying me. :) yes i was talking about this question http://stackoverflow.com/q/20634744/826657, I don't 100% blame anyone but all answers were downvoted simultaneouly as soon as the user Andro answered, as soon as I blindly question him why downvotes, and all downvotes were removed.

Comment: @twntee: Well it's not a bug - it's one person being annoying. There are many situations where one person can be annoying. The solution is usually flagging - if you believe the answerer is responsible for the downvotes, you could start by leaving a comment to ask, and to see whether there's a reason if so.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes Sir, as soon I asked him, all downvotes were removed. and all the answers were upvoted simultaneously. I flagged the answer and called for moderator attention and while I was searching meta I saw your answer and thought of bring it to your notice.

Comment: @twntee: Right, so I don't see that there's a problem. Occasionally there'll be bad behaviour - that doesn't mean it's worth *forcing* everyone to leave comments, or to make downvotes non-anonymous.

Comment: @JonSkeet yes Sir, forcing everyone to leave a comment or non anonymous downvotes will lead to revenge policies, and mess up all SO knowledge. Best thing is to accept this one annoying person and his downvotes and move on. After it is all about sharing knowledge and not about reps. :)

Comment: I think the first downvoter SHOULD (on questions AND answers) be forced to leave a comment about it - this is totally possible if @stackoverflow had the will to do it. It will improve the community by telling people what they did wrong i the opinion of the voter - the comment could even be anonymous. Political voting is already possible if you don't like someone's comment you can go and downvote them - and they can't see who you are or get a reason. This is already a problem, not seeing your downvoters doesn't fix it.

Comment: I did that, people told me that I have nothing to say about this, that's normal, I said that people who do that are some kind of cowards (hit and run), that human beings normally discuss. And then, the person who downvoted let a message that he wasn't a coward, and downvoted all my answers and discussion. If someone asks me, I will tell that this community is rude, and some moderator are in this state of mind.

Comment: @Quidam: Generalizing from "one person mass-downvoted me" (which will be reversed automatically) and "this community is rude" is a pretty big leap IMO.

Comment: It's a pain, well said, because sometimes, it's just so inappropriate and inadequate.. people just jump in and downvote for no clear reason.

Answer (score 17):

No.

Knowing this would almost always end in pointless "tit-for-tat" as you called it (even if not your specific case). It'd cause more harm than good - arguments, "revenge voting" and so on..

Comment: Actually, it would make people accountable for their votes so that they cannot simply vote down out of anger or spite.

Comment: -1 (if I had the rep) Revenge voting is made more likely by this. If you piss someone off, they just go to your profile, go through your posts and downvote them without any accountability.

Comment: @CarlSmith Such revenge-voting is systematically detected and reversed (see [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)). I can't think of a likely positive outcome that would come from knowing who downvoted an answer

Comment: +1 I stand corrected.

Comment: tit for tat can already exist - if you don't like someone's comment - you could go and downvote their question or answer - and they wouldn't be able to know who did it or why.

Answer (score 8):

you probably got dinged for calling subversion "trendy"; people can get mightly protective about their favorite tools (try saying something disparaging about Perl, for example)

;-)

Comment: Thanks Steven - the 'subversion' quip being the catalyst was my conclusion, too. :-)

Comment: Indeed. Especially, it seems VB.Net coders. One off-the-cuff comment I made on a question almost a year ago _still_ gets a trickle of downvotes every month :-(