# View vote details

Tags: support, down-votes, statistics, up-votes, revisions-list

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

Is it possible to check who has upvoted or downvoted your answer?

Comment: Welcome to Meta.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, there's no easy way.

You can sometimes figure it out by examining coincidental events, but even then you can't be sure.

Answer (score 7):

No, voting is anonymous. You don't really *need* to know who voted which way either :)

Comment: i found a posting here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1141603/mysql-help/1141611#1141611 thats why.

Comment: @zapping - the evidence given in the comments is purely circumstantial - I wouldn't rely on it.

Comment: yes, of course. so just wanted to know if its possible to get in anyway thats all.