# How to see who (up|down)voted?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, down-votes, up-votes, tracking

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [View vote details](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/36475/view-vote-details)
>   [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

Is this possible on SO? Similar to Facebook where you can see who "Liked" something.

Comment: None of your questions/answers on Stack Overflow have been downvoted. Are you concerned about a particular post? Or is this just a general question?

Comment: @Cody Gray: You gotta think more positive. My question includes upvotes as well.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

I don't believe this is possible, primarily for the fear of negative consequences (a downvoted user returning down-votes, for example). Requests for the feature typically meet with a status-bydesign (or similar) fate.

For reference: [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

It's also worth looking at the minor-compromise effort that Jeff implemented ( [Encouraging people to explain downvotes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes) ) which, in theory, encourages first-time down-voters to suggest ways in which the question/answer they're down-voting can be improved. And then hopes they remember in future.

Comment: I think this feature should be added, at least in some circumstances. Once in a blue moon I see -2 rep appear on all of my most recent answers. Clearly someone decided they don't like me -- because I suggested they provide a reproducible example of their error, because my answer was selected instead of theirs or who knows why -- and they decided to downvote all of my answers. I would like to be able to report this (assuming it's against the rules, which it should be if it's not). But without knowing who downvoted it I can't really prove anything, which isn't cool.

Comment: I would prever that only admins / site owners of the community should see who voted, but no one of us. I guess they can do this anyway already. If you think that someone mass-downvotes your posts because of anger or whatever, this could be considered be spam / manipulation. You could ask someone of the site team to handle this problem. I don't thing they will revert the votes, but at least they could ban the other user so it would stop. If users would be able to see who voted, it would probably result in more damage.

Comment: What I think would be not bad: If a user downvotes, he should fill a textline with the reason. This could be displayed for everyone (just the reason, not the user who voted down), so you know if it is justified. If it's not justified, you could report it.

Comment: @StanE: if someone makes a sequence of votes, either up *or* down, those votes are negated automatically by one of the scripts that runs overnight (around 03:00 UTC, I *think*). As to who can 'see' the votes, I understand that the devs, and anyone with access to the live database can do so, but it's removed - for obvious reasons - from [data.se] and the data dumps.

Comment: @StanE the textline suggestion makes a lot of sense. Unfortunately like everything else in life it may not be implemented in another decade.

Answer (score 20):

This is one of the main features of SO that the system of **up/down voting is anonymous**.
There is no way to know who up/downvoted you in any of the SE sites.

Comment: The information should be somewhere, how else is reputation impacted by user deletions. I'm not sure if the data explorer was around at the time of this answer, but it looks like a query can be formed.

Comment: Poking around I see the `UserId` is not available for the `UpMod` and `DownMod` vote types

Comment: There are negative consequences to unrestrained down voting.  I have been reading comments in social media that stackoverflow has become an unfriendly place. It is easier to cast aspirations then to say something constructive.  Ever read [Six thinking caps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Six_Thinking_Hats) by de Bono? There is a downside to too much black hat thinking. A compromise may be the ability to 1. send a rebuttal anonymously to the down voter 2. Require a reason for a down vote. Won't stop a troll but ....

Comment: We also not able to see who has accepted answer?

Comment: @AnkitShah an answer can only  be accepted by the OP obviously ?