# View upvoters or downvoters on a question

Tags: support, serial-voting

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Can we see who downvoted our question or answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66517/can-we-see-who-downvoted-our-question-or-answer)
>   [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

Are the voters behind a ballot anonymous to others? Can people see if i upvoted or downvoted on a question or vice-versa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know if mods have the power to see who voted, but for us laymen, voting is completely anonymous.  Who voted on whom has to be in the database somewhere, but I don't think Jeff is likely to release that anytime soon.

Comment: i was concerned if a certain reputation level opened it up. thanks, got the answer.

Comment: @Aditya: Glad to help.

Comment: Mods used to have access to this wayyyy back, but that caused... problems... so it's probably dev only at this point.