# Is there an easy way (or way at all) to see who votes down your question?

Tags: discussion, voting, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

This might seem a little silly but I feel kind of ticked that someone voted down my question.  I wasn't offensive and didn't do anything wrong.

I'm pretty sure it is this guy who thought I should have put it on a different site.  I know from experience that people on that site weren't good on a specific topic.  I look at this guy and he has voted down 1,000 questions.

Is there nothing I can do? I don't know why I care so much but it really irks me.

Comment: You shouldn't care so much. I don't think it would be good if ppl can see who voted down (or even up) for that matter. Take it in good sprit and enjoy :). To top it: a vote down is only -2 rep.

Comment: Well, It's good to know how the votes work.  I didn't know that it was a negative two to the vote.

Comment: See: [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers) and [See Who is Upvoting/ Downvoting My Question/Answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27534/see-who-is-upvoting-downvoting-my-question-answer) and also [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes)

Comment: @Welcome to Meta Stack Overflow, Scott! I feel for you, but this has been asked many times before (probably because, sooner or later, everyone wants to know about a particular downvote). See [this question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers) and its Linked and Related questions.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to welcome me.  Very nice of you.  Yeah, I guess you just have to suck it up!

Comment: Trying to be the new Grace Note, eh, @Shog?

Comment: @Pop: don't be sore 'cause I beat you to the punch...

Comment: @Shog, but the punchings, they result in the soreness!

Comment: @Pop - You wouldn't be here if you didn't like it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can comment on your post and ask the downvoter to explain their downvote, but they're under no obligation to, and as Shog9 points out in the comments, they won't see your comment unless they visit the post.

Comment: ...*and* they won't get notified of the comment...

Answer (score 2):

This would completely destroy voter anonymity and is *not* an implemented feature.

You can ask downvoters to comment but it is not required.