# What features is StackOverflow lacking?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, support, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

I have always felt that StackOverflow is a great site but do you think there are any features it is lacking?

In my opinion, the feature which is lacking is to know the identity of people who voted you up or down or making a record about what happened to your question. What are your views?

Comment: Please see [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers) as well as [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76193/is-there-an-easy-way-or-way-at-all-to-see-who-votes-down-your-question-closed), this has been requested and discussed at length.

Comment: I m not asking about only one feature rather i m asking about anything people think stack overflow lacks

Comment: @Pankaj - Individual feature requests are welcome, but a 'list of' type question asking for suggestions would not be very constructive.

Comment: @ tim post:What about multiple stack overflow accounts where user just vote himself from different account?

Comment: @Pankaj - You are welcome to raise individual concerns and feature requests in *indvidual* questions, provided that you don't duplicate one that has already been addressed. If you do find one, you can show your support for the idea with up votes.

Comment: @tim post:and what about this .people close the question down without reviewing it fully.For eg.the links you have given about duplicacy are just a small part of question and certainly not the whole question

Comment: @Pankaj - feature requests (and discussions surrounding them) need to be made individually. The bulk of your question does, in fact, address a topic that has been extensively discussed.

Comment: @ I had only one question "what features are lacking and people views " i myself gave a view

Comment: There is more like closing the question by just one user.A question must be reviewed by atleast five people to close it

Comment: Diamond moderators have final binding votes on all actions, and you can consider us the Stack Exchange overlords. As Tim pointed out, there is no value in this question by itself, and the bulk of your request has already been discussed and the conclusion was that voting is anonymous.

Comment: @ Diago: Stack overflow overlords !!! I think u have taken the moderator thing in wrong way . we need helpful reasonable moderators not overlords like you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voting is anonymous by design - this is not going to change. Anonymous voting is common and desirable in many voting systems in general.

Comment: anonymous voting is good if you have only two choices i.e to give vote or not to give but if their is a system where  somebody can down-vote them ,i think then there should be some explanation

Comment: @Pankaj Having an explanation for a down-vote is a different issue to knowing who down-voted you. It is not possible to down-vote and comment anonymously, but anonymous commenting also has its issues. Down-voting must be anonymous as there is potential for real problems with retribution. I have been down-voted in revenge many times even when just leaving negative but constructive comments. So no, down-voting must remain anonymous.

Comment: @ what about no downvoting or a warning before downvoting so that user can correct his mistake?

Comment: @Pankaj Users are already able to undo their down-vote in response to post edits, and also able to up-vote if they desire. The system works well enough in general as it is. It is not perfection, not can it be. It can at times seem unfair, but that's life. Work harder at getting rep, and get over it.

Comment: @chibacity:There is more like closing the question by just one user.A question must be reviewed by atleast five people to close it

Comment: @Pankaj If you want someone to talk to, there are chat rooms.

Comment: ok sorry to disturb you

Answer (score 1):

Upvoting and downvoting are the best features about SO. And keeping them anonymous is the icing on the cake. It's always good not to know who upvoted or downvoted you since this is a constructive forum. This would avoid having favourism or enimity amoung people in the community.

About what happened to your record or question when it is deleted is something I do agree since you will not know immediately on what went wrong.