# Regarding negative votes on Stack Overflow

Tags: support, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers)

How can I see the name of the user who gave me a negative vote? Please tell me.

Comment: tempting isn't it?

Comment: perhaps this is more suitable for stackoverflow meta?

Comment: Comment should be required if you want to make negative vote !!!

Comment: sometimes a comment is not required...

Comment: @Mitch Wheat: Don't be an ass.

Comment: @Teddy : I'm not. Sometimes it is obvious why a question needs a downvote with no comment required...

Comment: not my downvote BTW, but it is tempting! ;)

Comment: On a sidenote. StackOverflow is not a forum.

Comment: @ashish, as for mandatory comments: see [Encouraging people to explain down-votes](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135/encouraging-people-to-explain-down-votes).

Answer (score 5):

You can't. Sometimes they may leave a comment, sometimes not. If you feel there is an *unjustified* repeat set of downvotes happening, consider flagging for moderator attention.