# Who is downvoting my answers?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, down-votes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is serial voting and how does it affect me?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829/what-is-serial-voting-and-how-does-it-affect-me)

I see sudden downvoting for my answers without explanation (five downvotes in one minute).

[image]

I have seen [Can I tell who downvoted one of my answers?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/can-i-tell-who-downvoted-one-of-my-answers) and am *not* interested to know who downvoted my answers. But if all are downvoted by one user, chances are that this is spam/serial downloading. All I am interested in is the reason so that I can improve the answer.

Is there any special handling for such serial downvotes?  (I have no intention to go after the downvoter(s).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to tell. Sometimes it is just plain human nature and vindictiveness.

> Is there any special handling for such serial downvotes?

Yes, there is a script that catches these and reverts them. There is also some form of marking the offending user and if they become repeat offenders, they can face bans and worse.

If your reputation is not refunded within a couple of days, bring it to moderator attention (flag one of the questions and explain you suspect serial downvoting).

Comment: what if someone serial downvote as a pattern going for days. (Like 2-3 downvotes daily)

Comment: @Tilak - The moderators will be alerted and the person, if they don't desist after a few bans will get their account deleted. If you mean that they vote in such a way that the script doesn't catch them - alert the moderators yourself with evidence about the irregular voting patterns.

Comment: I also believe (but could not found any reference) If irregular voting pattern is found, It would be revered by moderators (and reputation will be recalculated as if no irregular voting is done).

Comment: @Tilak - Yes, if the automated scripts don't do this and the moderators do find in your favour, they will revert the downvotes.

Comment: From what I gather from these types of questions, it seems better to flag the answers privately than to open up a question on meta...right or wrong?

Comment: @iight - Well, I think the moderators would rather deal with these privately.